# What are all possible display types under xrandr?

Tags: display, xrandr

I know `VGA` , `LVDS`, `HDMI` and `DVI` exist.

Is there any list containing name all kind of such outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are possible:

**Intel driver - UMS:**

- VGA - Analog VGA output
- LVDS - Laptop panel
- DP1 - DisplayPort output
- TV - Integrated TV output
- TMDS-1 - First DVI SDVO output
- TMDS-2 - Second DVI SDVO output

**Intel driver - KMS:**

- LVDS1 - Laptop panel
- VGA1 - Analog VGA output
- DVI1 - Digital video output

**Radeon Driver:**

- VGA-0 - Analog VGA output
- LVDS - Laptop panel
- S-video - Integrated TV output
- DVI-0 - DVI output

**Also Possible:**

- HDMI - High-Definition Multimedia Interface
- DVI - Digital Visual Interface
- DP - DisplayPort
- S-video - S-Video

**References:**

- [ThinkWiki: Xorg RandR 1.2 - Output Port Names](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#Output_port_names)
- [Gentoo Wiki: Xrandr Screen Query](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xrandr#Screen_Query)

Comment: VGA1 is the primary VGA, right? So should VGA1 be a kind of output. If it is, then will the displays be named VGA11 , VGA12, etc. in case there are two of VGA1 type displays? Same for LVDS and LVDS1

Comment: I am afraid that my knowledge of xrandr does not extend that far :(